# TYPO3 backend thumbnail generation

Tags: thumbnails, backend, typo3-7.6.x

While developing a web site we deleted manually the typo3temp directory.
This caused all the already generated backend thumbnails to be deleted.

We have a backup, and are in dev phase, so no big deal, but nonetheless the event raised a question: is there a way to trigger the generation of backend thumbnails that have been already uploaded?

We are using TYPO3 7.6

Answer (score 0):

No there is currently no way for that.

But it would be possible to create a command controller that regenerates all processed files again based on the processed files records in the database.

Comment: Thanks, of course I as aware of the coding way, but I was hoping for something ready made